# Test Android Apps in real Device

Tags: android, android-studio-2.1

I have developed an Android application using Android Studio. It is working smoothly on Simulator. But after testing on a real device by exporting the apk file it throws an exception.

So I want to solve that problem by testing in a real device, but I'm not able to do it.

There is an error like this in the image:

[image]

How do I test it on my real device?

I have an android Phone Samsung Galaxy j3 (model no: sm-j320f).

Comment: Check if you have your device driver installed

Comment: Make sure you've enabled adb debugging in developer options and installed the USB driver https://developer.android.com/studio/run/win-usb.html

Comment: follow [this](https://www.kingoapp.com/root-tutorials/how-to-enable-usb-debugging-mode-on-android.htm)

Comment: @KenWolf your link is for google nexus devices. Here's the good link : https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html

Comment: i've tried everything i could , i think there is problem with my usb driver of system.

Answer (score 0):

Just plug your device by usb, enable developer option and then you can choose your device when you click on run.

Answer (score 0):

Under the portable devices, right click on your connected device name, and uninstall. After that unplug the and then plug it back in, wait for some time. Your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

You must first install the device drivers to your computer and then enable the developer mode in your phone check here also: https://developer.android.com/studio/run/device.html

Answer (score 0):

On android device:
go to Settings > Developer Options

and enable it

Then enable "USB Debugging"

Connect your device to your PC, then in Android Studio, click on Run button then double click your device name.

If this doesn't work , you may need to install your device's driver on your pc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the [Samsung USB Driver for Mobile Phones](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117). You then need to enable developper mode on your device. Then, developper studio should allow you to debug on your test device.
You can find additionnal info [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/oem-usb.html)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to sort usb device issue since your computer is not able to install the drivers for the usb you connected I can see this in your image.
Follow these steps :

1. Completely Shutdown your computer and remove the power cable. (Also remove the battery if you own a laptop). Leave it unplugged for about 5-10 minutes and then re-plug the power cord (and the battery). Turn On your computer and check if your USB devices are working.
2. If you own a laptop:

   - Turn off your laptop.
   - Unplug the AC power adapter and the battery.
   - Leave your computer without power for about 15 minutes.
   - Reinsert the battery
   - Turn on your laptop.
   - Plug one by one all USB devices.
   - Check if the USB not recognized problem is solved and the USB devices are working.
   - Plug the AC power adapter.

     3. Change the USB cable that connects your computer with the USB device.

Hope this will sort Your issue with USB as this works for me..

Next

1. Go to this [Samsung Usb Drivers](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000117)
   Download and Install Usb Drivers ..
   Now connect your device with your computer /Laptop via usb cable..
   Wait for drivers to install completely..
   Now
2. On android device: go to Settings > Developer Options and enable it
   Then enable "USB Debugging"
3. Start Android Studio Click on Debug Button check if your device name is there in connected device
   If the device name is their in connected device name,then you can go with debugging.
   Hope this helps..Cheers!!!

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue by ***installing PdaNet+***

Download it from
http://pdanet.co/a/

Check if it made any difference and let me know

Comment: thanks @Rissmon Suresh , this software solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

On some android devices you need to enable the Install via usb setting or the phone will block the install. 
Go to settings > additional settings > developer options > Install via usb.